# Manual Installation of PHP 5

Tags: windows-7, php, iis-7

I've manually installed PHP 5.3 in IIS 7 (using Windows 7). I could generally run PHP scripts but I can't seem to create files(and directories). I've checked the php.ini files (*yeah, two, there's the production ini and the development ini, should I just rename one to just 'php.ini' to use?*) and I allows creating files.

I've gave permission to IIS_IUSRS to full do stuff in the directory where I'll be creating files.

Is there anything else that I might've missed?

Here's the instructions I used as reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: Why don't you install PHP via Web Platform Installer: http://php.iis.net/ ; http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx -- it should configure these moments automatically. TBH I have manual installation as well .. but it worked fine without any extra "voodoo dancing" (although I need to double check it when get home).

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to try the manual path first. I'll just go for the installation packed from Microsoft then.